# Scribus: Master Page features lost behind image

Tags: layers, master-page, scribus

I have a Master Page in my document set as a footer, with document name and page number. This appears on most pages.

When I paste an image or text frame onto a page with the Master Page applied, the footer is lost behind the image.

I have tried: `right click > Layer > Lower to Bottom` and also lowering the layer with the image to the bottom of the document.

I have a layer entitled Master Pages, with all of the Master Page information on it, which is at the top of the document.

How can I ensure the Master Page information stays on top of everything?

Comment: Are you saying that you are putting images on certain pages near the bottom, where your document name and page number normally appear? So you want to show the page information on top of your image? Are those pages just a tiny minority, or are many pages affected?

Comment: My images are not at the bottom but full page. I used the hack from @a.l.e, with a little editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next (1.6) Scribus version will allow to shuffle around layers across pages and master pages.
And you will be able to correctly achieve your goal.

If you're not brave enough to use the development version 1.5.x, you will have to go through more or less ugly workarounds. Depending on the specific type of document you're working on.

The simplest workaround:

- In the master page, create the "visual elements" as you are used to;
- Group them and send them to the "Scrapbook" (in the context menu or "Item > Send to Scrapbook");
- Delete the visual elements from the master page (or make them othwerwise invisible / not printable)
- On each page where you want the footer to appear on top of the "local" items, double click on the Scrapbook item to place it at the same place where it was when you added it to the Scrapbook (it's easier to do, than than to explain... Promised.)

So:

- You might need two Scrapbook items if you have facing pages.
- You might want to create two (set of) master pages with and without "always on top" visuals.
- Simply putting guide lines (instead of content) on the master page might also be a solution).

Comment: This works but it also screws up my formatting: where I have a right-hand page footer, the group pasted to/from the scrapbook includes an additional carriage return (notated by an 'r') at the end of the line, throwing it out of line. Any idea how to stop that? By not grouping them, but selecting all and then sending to Scrapbook, I can edit them individually to remove the additional carriage return, but that's a horrible hack.

Comment: I can replicate the injection of a carriage return, but I don't see any change in the layout. In the development version the issue does not seem to be there anymore, so I'm don't feel it like a urgent bug... But I'd need to know how your footer looks like (and which version of Scribus you are using) to help you further.

Comment: I need to "rebuke" my friend a.l.e for his choice of words (grin, wink). And I commend him for always finding a hack.

Comment: Thanks @a.l.e Apologies for not replying sooner. I used this method but found that ungrouped was just as effective, and more flexible as it was easier to correct the 'carriage return' thing on right-hand pages.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be very brave for using Scribus version 1.5.2. We are using it for a long time and we never lost a document nor data.

If you consider the answer above a horrible hack, please just try version 1.5.2 and arrange your layers as you like.

You can parallel-install several versions of Scribus and also can keep a copy of your document in 1.4.x-format in case you are not sattisfied. So it might take you one or two hours to try it out, and you got almost nothing to lose.